# How to push updates from local repository to BitBucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

So I made a local repository, and committed some changes to the BitBucket Repo.

After that, I made some changes in the local repository.

I tried to push those files to the BitBucket, using git push origin master command. It said All Files are Up to Date. But I don't see any changes on the BitBucket page.

Any help on this please?

Comment: Have you added and committed the changes locally?

Comment: I did, and it said that your branch is up to date with origin/master. Changes not staged for commit (then file names) then un-tracked files (files) then it says not changes added to commit.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't added them. See `git help add`.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have uncommitted changes.
Looks like you forgot to add files to the staging area.

execute a `git status` and check to see if you have un tracked/modified files

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You got this message, did you?

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Git try to help you and explain to you what exactly you will need to do
**use "git add ..." to update what will be committed**

So just do it to pushing your changes on the remote server

```
$ git add -A ./
$ git commit -m "add some comment here"
$ git push origin master
```

And you can read manual about `git add` here

```
$ git help add
```

or

```
$ man git-add
```